# De Longs test on ROC curves?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, confidence-interval, auc, model-comparison

I have two different ROC curves for Model A and B. I wanted to calculate the DeLongs test to identify the statisical significance of the difference between the model.

model_A_tpr = [0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1]

model_A_fpr = [0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 1]

model_B_tpr = [0, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7, 0.9, 1])

model_B_fpr = [0, 0.15, 0.25, 0.35, 0.45, 1])

I have come across this implementation of the [DeLongs test](https://github.com/yandexdataschool/roc_comparison/blob/master/compare_auc_delong_xu.py) but it requires model probabilities which I do not have.